# Why were all of my points stripped on the basis of asking this question?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Software Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Does software engineering in C derive a new insight into the halting problem?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/441076/does-software-engineering-in-c-derive-a-new-insight-into-the-halting-problem)

The official SE guidance on SPAM:

> [How to not be a
> spammer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)
>
> **Don't include links except to support what you've written.**

Specifically approves of linking to a paper for the purpose of providing background information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can this question be improved so that I can get an answer?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9380/how-can-this-question-be-improved-so-that-i-can-get-an-answer)

Comment: @GregBurghardt The question was deleted locked on the basis of using a dishonest definition of SPAM. I provided a link to my paper and the source-code of my system only so that the full depth of the question could be fully understood.

Comment: Even if the link to your own research paper was removed from the question, it still suffers from the same basic problems as your original question. A question like this would be more appropriate for the [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) community. They specifically have a [halting-problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halting-problem) tag. Just be sure to read their guidelines on asking questions. I'm fairly certain a question there will be marked as spam if you link to your own research paper.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Saying that a research paper is anything like unsolicited commercial email is ridiculous. I just want to get people to understand what I am saying and thereby validate it.

Comment: The term "spam" is used in a more general sense than unsolicited e-mail. Typically anything unsolicited in digital format is considered spam.

Comment: @GregBurghardt None the the questions on SE are ever solicited, so under that definition all of SE is SPAM. Calling the addition of my research paper SPAM is comparable to calling a new born puppy a "mad dog" (with rabies) on the basis that both are dogs.

Comment: I think that this is just the wrong community to ask a question like that. I think you will have more luck at CS.SE - just don't link to your paper, because they will probably think of it as shameless self-promotion as well.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I have asked this same question everywhere. Everyone everywhere on SE votes on it down without any valid critique. My words are treated as if claimed to have a mathematical proof that a particular dead cockroach is the creator of the universe. I got the former editor in chief of JACM to review my work with 30 emails and he rejected it on the basis that he did not understand the x86 language.

Comment: Soliciting feedback is basically off topic on all StackExchange sites, except for CodeReview.SE. You need a tangible, real, concrete problem to solve in most of these communities. Your question, while clearly well thought out, is not seeking a solution to a concrete problem. This was explained in your first meta post.

Comment: @GregBurghardt CodeReview didn't want to look at it either. How much more concrete can I get than a fully operational system? [Complete halt deciding system](https://liarparadox.org/2022_09_07.zip)


[Compiles under Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/)

Comment: I asked a [related question on meta about this issue](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9424/118878).

Comment: @GregBurghardt That is very helpful, thanks. What about the links to the source-code of the complete system, would they be considererd spam?

Comment: That might be a good subject for another question, honestly. I don't think it was the link to the source code that was causing concern, IMO.

Comment: @GregBurghardt It seems to be "slap in the face" obvious that that when Px is correctly simulated by any simulating halt decider Hx that Px never reaches its "return" instruction in 1 to ∞ simulated steps. Because of this is seems quite nuts that I have consistently gotten the resistance that I have to this straight forward software engineering idea from many dozens of people over the last 12 months.

Comment: @GregBurghardt How was I supposed to know that I am not allowed to post links to my paper? Defining a link to one's own paper to provide details that cannot be expressed in a short post would never be called SPAM anywhere else. I am not a mind reader.

Comment: While the title is provocative, it would be good to read the [guidance on self-promotion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). That would answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: @GregBurghardt How is it reasonable that I be punished for not knowing about this non-standard definition of SPAM? **Don't include links except to support what you've written.** That is exactly what I did. I also included links to the fully operational software system that I was referring to.

Comment: @GregBurghardt The definition of SPAM that you provided proves that the link to my paper does not meet this definition.  **if you mention your product, website, etc. in your question or answer, you must disclose your affiliation in your post.**  This says the exact opposite of **Any links to papers that you wrote will be considered as SPAM and you will be penalized**

Answer (score 9):

Your post was deleted for spam, probably because it reads like you are trying to promote your own publication and not ask good-faith, on-topic questions. Posts that are deleted for spam come with a removal of 100 reputation points. Because reputation can't go below 1, you are left with a single reputation point.

It also looks like the spam flag may have placed additional restrictions on your ability to ask and answer questions for the next week or so.

If you want to continue to participate here, I recommend checkout out the [Help Center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help), particularly the guidance on [asking questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: I am just trying to get an accurate review of my work. The above post is an entirely different presentation than the post with a similar name.

Comment: Everyone on SE that reviews my work either rejects it out-of-hand without review by merely voting it down, or forms a rebuttal based on a false assumption. When they make a false assumption they never see my proof that their assumption is false having switched to rejected out-of-hand mode.

Comment: @polcott We don't review work here. We answer questions about working within the systems development life cycle - methods, practices, requirements, architecture, design, testing. quality assurance, configuration management, build, release, deployment, operations, maintenance, and so on. I read [your post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/441076/4) and not only do I not see a question about the SDLC, but it seems like it only exists to link to a publication that you wrote on ResearchGate. Because it's promoting your own work, it's spam and was treated as such.

Comment: Software engineering itself pertains to much more than the SDLC. When-so-ever computer systems are created to solve a definable problem and some rigorous process is applied to the derivation of this solution we have an instance of software engineering. When I used categories of sets of computations I was able to reverse-engineer the process required for a software process to determine which category that a finite string belongs to.

Comment: @polcott The scope of this site is the SDLC. Not everything that someone could argue is part of software engineering is on topic here. Things that are not questions, that don't fit our defined scope, and only exist to promote your content don't belong here. Unless you can explain how this question meets our scope definition and remove self-promotion, there's nothing else to do here.

Comment: I am just trying to get my words so that they can be understood. I need feedback for that. What I said is inaccurately characterized as SPAM. Please give me my points back!

Comment: @polcott No. You posted something that meets our definition of spam. Appropriate actions were taken. If you can fix the whole question to the point where it's both on-topic and the self-promotion is removed, then it can be reviewed. However, I don't see a way to make it into a question that would be considered on-topic here.

Comment: There is no self-promotion, it was only background material that provides  additional details needed to fully understand the question. I can't do anything with the question because it is deleted and locked.

Comment: It is flatly dishonest to penalize me 100 points for SPAM when what I did is nothing like spam. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamming

Comment: How was I supposed to know that I am not allowed to post links to my paper? Defining a link to one's own paper to provide details that cannot be expressed in a short post would never be called SPAM anywhere else. I am not a mind reader.