# Will removing link to author's own research paper be enough to make this question not spam?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, spam

This question is an extension of another meta post: [Why were all of my points stripped on the basis of asking this question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9417/118878).

The [original question was marked as spam, and deleted](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/441076/revisions). The meta question asked why their reputation was affected by the removal of the question. The meta question was answered in a satisfactory manner, in my opinion. Looking at the revision history of the original SE question, I can see a link to an academic paper that was authored by the person who asked the question. I understand why the question was marked as spam, but otherwise the question does not look like an attempt at shameless self-promotion.

I do not have sufficient reputation to edit the question, so I am not able to remove the offending link. It seems the original intent of the question has been muddied by a simple link that could be removed by any one of us who have that ability.

If we remove the link to the OP's academic paper, can we undelete the question, remove the spam mark, and reopen the question?

Original question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/441076/118878

---

Addendum: the community might still vote to close it, but at least the question can stand on its own merits rather than being bogged down by a technicality about spam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would such edits make it not spam? Yes.

Make it suitable for undeletion and reopening? It's still an off-topic question. Aside from the title, I don't see any questions, on- or off-topic. Even if you could formulate good questions, the subject matter is more closely related to Computer Science than Software Engineering. Standard practice across the network is to only undo actions that are likely to result in positive results. Since I can't see this question being reopened (or remaining open if it were opened), it doesn't make sense to undo the actions.

There's also a history with the user and this question isn't a one-off instance. The user has a history of asking similar questions that were excessively down voted and deleted - 1 by the Community user for being closed and downvoted, 3 by community members, and 1 by spam flag. This is bordering on automatic blocking of asking questions, and if not, continued deletions would probably trigger an automatic flag that would result in a mod message and perhaps suspension for consistently low quality contributions.

It's not worth the effort to salvage a question from someone who is not acting in good faith.

Comment: This other question by the same user has a link to their research paper as well: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/430016/118878

Comment: @GregBurghardt: and 51 minutes ago it was deleted by the community bot as Spam, too. Maybe your comment triggered this?